# Is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not sure questions of the on-topic definition of this site (if the below question is not on-topic does anyone know where I could post this that it would be on-topic?)

I'm doing a monte carlo simulations at the moment and the model keeps stopping after a number of runs that doesn't appear to be related to anything. It also doesn't appear to be a problem with the change in the inputs being used (when I print them, they look normal). Is there a reason for this that is likely to be due to the code? I think it might be that the computer I am using is just not high spec enough to deal with the running the model. Is that plausible?

Comment: If this is your entire proposed question, it doesn't contain enough information to be meaningfully answerable.

Comment: This question is not plausible for meta.

Comment: _"at the moment and the model keeps stopping after a number of runs that doesn't appear to be related to anything  .... Is there a reason for this that is likely to be due to the code?"_ What else could you think of? Is it normal on your machine, programs stop working after a while without any reason?

Comment: 'What else could you think of?' - data.

Comment: @MartinJames _"It also doesn't appear to be a problem with the change in the inputs being used ..."_

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think that the computer might be getting low on memory. I think that might be causing the model to crash. Bear in mind I am clueless about computers.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User Why are you programming if you are clueless about computers? That seems like a bad idea...

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User _"I think that the computer might be getting low on memory."_ And you don't think that could be caused by your code actually? What a miraculous incidence, it happens when your program runs, isn't it? Use a decent tool like valgrind to detect memory leaks in your program.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Because I have to. I am not interested in programming I just need to do some. Sucks to be me.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User _"Because I have to ..."_ You've been either choosing the wrong job, or the wrong class ...

Comment: Pretty much, I didn't realise I'd have to do anything more than a bit of high-level language data analysis until 2/3rds of the way through a experimentally orientated PhD. Now I'm stuck with it and I am not enjoying it and can't wait for it to be over. As I say - sucks to be me.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ maybe you are right, maybe I should cut my losses and just quit. My confidence, mental stability and physical health are shot already. Maybe it is just time to go before I burn out completely. Maybe I should go and ask that question academics, might be more on-topic there.

Comment: Should I delete this question? It seems that this is not a useful meta topic (-7). I'm sorry my understanding of computers was not good enough to work out how to ask this question in a good way. That's why I went to meta and not the main site in the first instance. It seems that asking about how to make a question of this sort on topic when I don't know what I am doing is not a good question to ask on meta.

Comment: Where should I go when I'm trying to figure out where and how to ask about something about which I have such infantile understanding that I can't figure out where to post it, how to search for it and might not recognise a useful bit of information even if I saw it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not *remotely* on-topic.

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

Questions seeking debugging help must provide code that shows the problem (which is woefully missing from yours).

"Stopping" is better than "It doesn't work", but still isn't a very specific problem statement either.

This page may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This isn't really the angle I am driving at, I want to know if it is possible that a lack of memory could cause the code I am running to crash. I have no clue how computers really work so I don't know whether or not this is the case.

I don't want someone to debug the code, I want someone to tell me something more general about computing and I do not know if that kind of question is on-topic at stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, of course it could cause that. We will have absolutely *no idea* if thats the case though because we can't see code. You haven't even looked it up in Task Manager (or the linux equivalent) to see how much memory is being used! This isn't a programming question as put. Not yet anyways.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User Note that general computing questions are on-topic at Super User. The question *you* posted would not meet their guidelines either though. "How to check a process memory" would meet it (though Google first, its probably already been asked).

Comment: Well I have tried to figure it out in Windows using task manager. But then this is running in a virtual box of Ubuntu - make of that what you will. I don't know how to do it in a virtual box of a Linux system. I've tried googling that and not really got anywhere but as I don't know what I'm doing I'm probably searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User Then I would ask *that* question on either Super User or Linux/Unix, or even Ask Ubuntu ("How do I check a process's memory usage?") Make sure to include the platform you are using. It is definitely *not* on-topic here.